# Simple Mastermind game

Tags: java, game

This is pretty much my first "bigger" application besides some "Hello World!" stuff, so I would appreciate critiques to improve my style.

It can be started with `Mastermind.play(<difficulty-setting>)`, with  being a number from 1 (easy) to 10 (hard).

```
public class Mastermind {
    public static void play(int difficulty) {
        int round = 1;
        int[] zahl = getZufallsZahl(difficulty);
        int[] tries = Try(round,difficulty);
        int[] hits = getHits(zahl,tries);
        while (hits[0]!=difficulty) {
            System.out.println("Direct hits: "+hits[0]+"\nIndirect hits: "+hits[1]);
            round++;
            if (round%(int)(Math.random()*10)==0) {
                System.out.println(motivator[(int)(Math.random()*(motivator.length))]);
            }
            tries = Try(round,difficulty);
            hits = getHits(zahl,tries);
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You got it in "+round+" rounds!");
    }
    public static int[] getZufallsZahl(int difficulty) {
        if (difficulty>10) {
            difficulty=10;
        }
        int[] zahl = new int[difficulty];
        int same=1;
        for (int i=0; i<difficulty; i++) {
            // This loop is quite ugly because of the check over the same variable, but I didn't want to use a break with a label (outerloop: for [...] break outerloop;)
            do {
                same=0;
                zahl[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
                for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
                    if (zahl[i]==zahl[j]) {
                        same=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (same==1);
        }
        return zahl;
    }



    // Below function is copy pasted! :O (yes I am ashamed for it, but it's "only" a niche-feature, so yeah :/)
    private static String ordinal(int i) {
        String[] sufixes = new String[] { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
        switch (i % 100) {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
            return i + "th";
        default:
            return i + sufixes[i % 10];
        }
    }
    // Above function is copy pasted! :O



    private static int[] Try(int round, int difficulty) {
        int[] intry = evalTry(getTry(round));
        while (!verifyTry(intry) || intry.length<(difficulty-1) || intry.length>difficulty) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            intry = evalTry(getTry(round));
        }
        // This sort of copying of the array makes sure that a 3 element array becomes a 4 element array with a leading 0 to make it easier to process it afterwards.
        int[] tries = new int[difficulty];
        for (int i=(intry.length-1), k=(difficulty-1); i>=0; k--,i--) {
            tries[k]=intry[i];
        }
        return tries;
    }
    private static String getTry(int round) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String in = "";
        System.out.print("This is your "+ordinal(round)+" try: ");
        try {
            in = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return in;
    }
    private static int[] evalTry(String in) {
        int[] intry = new int[in.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<in.length(); i++) {
            intry[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.substring(i,i+1));
        }
        return intry;
    }
    private static boolean verifyTry(int[] intry) {
        for (int i=0; i<intry.length; i++) {
            for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
                if (intry[i] == intry[j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static int[] getHits(int[] zahl,int[] tries) {
        // 0 for direct, 1 for indirect.
        int[] hits = new int[2];
        for (int i=0; i<zahl.length; i++) {
            if (zahl[i]==tries[i]) {
                hits[0]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<zahl.length; i++) {
            for (int k=0; k<zahl.length; k++) {
                if (zahl[i]==tries[k] && i!=k) {
                    hits[1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return hits;
    }
    private static String[] motivator={"You can do it!","Think... Think!","Come on!","You nearly have it!","The force is with you!","FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUU!","This game is stupid anyways...","...","Disregard dumbness, acquire intelligence.","Stop failing, start winning!"};
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class Mastermind {
    public static void play(int difficulty) {
        int round = 1;
        int[] zahl = getZufallsZahl(difficulty);
```

zahl? What's that?

```
        int[] tries = Try(round,difficulty);
```

Usually we have classes capitalized, with methods have the first letter lowercase. Because you don't follow convention, that makes this bit harder to read

```
        int[] hits = getHits(zahl,tries);
```

Ok, but tries implies multiple tries. This is a single attempt, and the multiplicity is in the code assignment.

```
        while (hits[0]!=difficulty) {
            System.out.println("Direct hits: "+hits[0]+"\nIndirect hits: "+hits[1]);
            round++;
            if (round%(int)(Math.random()*10)==0) {
                System.out.println(motivator[(int)(Math.random()*(motivator.length))]);
            }
            tries = Try(round,difficulty);
            hits = getHits(zahl,tries);
```

You've repeated code before and in the loop. If you use a break in the middle of the loop, you can avoid that. (If somebody told you not to use break, they were wrong).

```
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You got it in "+round+" rounds!");
    }

    public static int[] getZufallsZahl(int difficulty) {
        if (difficulty>10) {
            difficulty=10;
        }
        int[] zahl = new int[difficulty];
        int same=1;
        for (int i=0; i<difficulty; i++) {
            // This loop is quite ugly because of the check over the same variable, but I didn't want to use a break with a label (outerloop: for [...] break outerloop;)
            do {
                same=0;
                zahl[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
                for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
                    if (zahl[i]==zahl[j]) {
                        same=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (same==1);
        }
```

Yeah... Don't do that.  Instead:

1. Start with an array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
2. Shuffle the array
3. Shrink the array to the correct size.

That'll be easier to follow

```
        return zahl;
    }



    // Below function is copy pasted! :O (yes I am ashamed for it, but it's "only" a niche-feature, so yeah :/)
```

Nothing wrong with copy-pasting. You should take advantage of code that other people wrote as much as possible. The problem with copy-paste is multiple copies of the same code in your program, not taking working code from elsewhere.

```
    private static String ordinal(int i) {
        String[] sufixes = new String[] { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
        switch (i % 100) {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
            return i + "th";
        default:
            return i + sufixes[i % 10];
        }
    }
    // Above function is copy pasted! :O



    private static int[] Try(int round, int difficulty) {
        int[] intry = evalTry(getTry(round));
```

intry? What does that mean? Try to pick helpful variable names

```
        while (!verifyTry(intry) || intry.length<(difficulty-1) || intry.length>difficulty) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            intry = evalTry(getTry(round));
        }
```

As before, don't duplicate the contents of the loop before the loop.

```
        // This sort of copying of the array makes sure that a 3 element array becomes a 4 element array with a leading 0 to make it easier to process it afterwards.
```

What? That's a confusing way to explain what you are doing here. Just say that you are filling the array with leading zeros.

```
        int[] tries = new int[difficulty];
        for (int i=(intry.length-1), k=(difficulty-1); i>=0; k--,i--) {
            tries[k]=intry[i];
```

What if intry is too long rather then too short?

```
        }
        return tries;
    }
    private static String getTry(int round) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String in = "";
        System.out.print("This is your "+ordinal(round)+" try: ");
        try {
            in = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

For quick and dirty application, I suggest `throw new RuntimeException(ex);` log messages are liable to be missed.

```
        }
        return in;
    }
    private static int[] evalTry(String in) {
        int[] intry = new int[in.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<in.length(); i++) {
            intry[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.substring(i,i+1));
        }
        return intry;
    }
    private static boolean verifyTry(int[] intry) {
        for (int i=0; i<intry.length; i++) {
            for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
```

Why do you keep making your loops backwards for no reason?

```
                if (intry[i] == intry[j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static int[] getHits(int[] zahl,int[] tries) {
        // 0 for direct, 1 for indirect.
        int[] hits = new int[2];
```

I'd suggest storing the hits in two variables rather then as a two element array. Just stick them in the array when you return.

```
        for (int i=0; i<zahl.length; i++) {
            if (zahl[i]==tries[i]) {
                hits[0]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<zahl.length; i++) {
            for (int k=0; k<zahl.length; k++) {
                if (zahl[i]==tries[k] && i!=k) {
                    hits[1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return hits;
    }

    private static String[] motivator={"You can do it!","Think... Think!","Come on!","You nearly have it!","The force is with you!","FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUU!","This game is stupid anyways...","...","Disregard dumbness, acquire intelligence.","Stop failing, start winning!"};
```

The name `motivator` should probably be plural.

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated my question with the changed code I wrote. I have a question thought, is it really better if I make an infinite loop in which I break out of instead of just declaring the variables beforehand and using them in the Statement for the loop? Or did I misunderstand you on that part? ("You've repeated code before and in the loop.")

Comment: @Mastermind, I have to admit people will disagree on whether the infinite loop is better. I think it is better to have an infinite loop that you break out of. Its better if you can avoid using `break`, but its more important to avoid duplication.